# GoogleApiClient is not working for TV application

Tags: android-tv

using **GoogleApiClient** I am able to get location in this way:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                   .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                   .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                   .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                   .build();
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        Log.d("the lat is",mLatitudeText);
        mLongitudeText = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        Log.d("the lon is",mLongitudeText);
    }
}
```

but this does not work for android TV application. Neither `onConnected` nor `onConnectionFailed` is called. I did not find any documentation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android developer documentation on [handling TV hardware](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/hardware.html#handle-features) states:

> TVs have a different purpose from other devices, and so they do not have hardware features that other Android-powered devices often have. For this reason, the Android system does not support the following features for a TV device:
>
> GPS - android.hardware.location.gps

That might be tripping you up.

The documentation offers some hints on solutions:

> TVs are stationary, indoor devices, and do not have built-in global positioning system (GPS) receivers. If your app uses location information, you can still allow users to search for a location, or use a static location provider such as a zip code configured during the TV device setup.